# Python: Adding 3 weeks to any date

Tags: python, date

I need help with a program.
How do I add 3 weeks (21 days) to any given date when the user can control the date?

The user will enter the date YYYY-MM-DD.

Below I'm trying to locate the hyphen and make sure there is only 2. This is what I have so far but all it does is repeat itself, can someone tell me where I went wrong ?:

```
date = raw_input("Enter date: ")
i = 0
while i <= len(date):
    if date[i] != "-":
    i = i + 1
print date
```

Now I'm picking out year, month, day. Is there an easier way to do this cause I need to account for the change months etc ?

```
year = date[0:4]
month = date[5:7]
day = date[9:11]
```

thanks

Answer (score 81):

Use [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module to the task. You create a datetime aware object and add 21 days timedelta object to it.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> u = datetime.datetime.strptime("2011-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
>>> d = datetime.timedelta(days=21)
>>> t = u + d
>>> print(t)
2011-01-22 00:00:00
```

Comment: thank you so much, but i think i might have to do it the old fashion way... we were never taught datetime.

Comment: senthil - thanks for the encouragement ! i think i gonna go read head, i really dont want to write tons of code for one that can be so simplified. i cant thnk you enough for showing me.

Comment: @monica, if you didn't use datetime and timedelta, you would definitely need a bunch of code to account for the different lengths of the months - especially Feb during leap years, and incrementing the year if the 3 weeks would push you past the end of Dec. etc.

Comment: @gnibbler, it looks like im doing it the long way, found out that im not allowed to use datetime

Answer (score 17):

You can use a datetime.timedelta object to represent 3 weeks and then just add that to the datetime object that represents the user's input.

```
import datetime

date = raw_input("Enter date: ")
aDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d")
threeWeeks = datetime.timedelta(weeks = 3)

print aDate + threeWeeks
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior for details about using the strptime method.

Comment: q, thanks for all you help, and responding so quickly. im very grateful.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, I am sure its the shortest and easiest way to go

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

period = date.today() + relativedelta(weeks=+1)
```

Comment: I really appreciate this, Randall. Sometimes a third party package makes everything so much more readable.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `datetime.strptime` to get input from user as date

```
from datetime import datetime
i = str(raw_input('date'))
try:
    dt_start = datetime.strptime(i, '%Y, %m, %d')
except ValueError:
    print "Incorrect format"
```

and then to add 3 weeks (21 days)

```
dt_start = dt_start + datetime.timedelta(days=21)
```

There you go

Comment: (1) you don't need `str()` around `raw_input()`. (2) both `strptime()` and `timedelta()` are already shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5189806/4279) -- I don't see what your answer adds here to the answer posted 4 years ago.