# Python datetime.timedelta not working with in arg

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to do a web scraper with selenium which will run as a AWS lambda function every week to book a time slot for me to go and play some tennis. My booking site is releasing new bookable time slots at midnight 2 weeks ahead of time. I have a lambda function that will run every Wednesday at midnight.

My issue is actually when I'm using `datetime.timedelta(days=14)` I get a compiler error for the inarg days.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r3fn.png)

```
bookingTime = nowInUtc + timedelta(days=14)
```

I have seen multiple examples of this syntax:

[Python: Adding 3 weeks to any date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189777/python-adding-3-weeks-to-any-date/5189806)

[Adding days to a date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-days-to-a-date-in-python)

What am I missing?

Im using Jetbrainz PyCharm Idea
Python 3.9.7

my imports

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
```

Comment: Please post the entire code sample, and the error message as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works and gets the date two weeks from now. If you want to know why you code doesn't work, you'll have to post your code :)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
in_two_weeks = now + timedelta(days=14)
print(in_two_weeks)
```

Comment: if you want UTC time, import `timezone` from the datetime module as well and use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

Comment: Ok im stupid. Its just the color red in my idea. My code works. I just assumed it was a compiler error. Thanks for the help!